# jQuery - Only run a function AFTER another has finished running

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have a long list that I want to 'paginate' using jQuery Cycle. There's about 40 items in the list, and I want to show 5 at a time, with a Next/Prev at the bottom.

This is what I'm trying to do:   http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/vmdaM/97/

The first function would divide the list into chunks of 5 items, and then jQuery Cycle would run on the result.

I've got the list chunked up into 5 items just fine. But jQuery Cycle keeps telling me that it doesn't have any divs to work with.

How can I make sure the first function is completely finished slicing up the list before jQuery Cycle initiates?

Thanks

Terry

Comment: It's already guaranteed to have already run. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: console says `jquery.cycle.lite.js:28   terminating; too few slides: 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed as @minitech mentions the for loop is guaranteed to be complete by the time you do your cycle plugin initialization.

The problem is your selector:

```
$('#projectList').cycle(...)
```

The `projectList` element doesn't have any divs in it, only a single `ul`.

Change your selector like so:

```
$('#projectList ul').cycle(...)
```

Of course... your `wrapAll` call has made the markup incorrect. You now have `ul > div > li` which is almost certainly not valid... But hey, it should work anyway, at least get you a little further :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `<div>`s are still nested within the `<ul>`. You need to remove them from there. I have no idea what went wrong, and I can't get that to work properly. Are you missing a stylesheet? Anyway, here's my rewrite, which uses correct markup:

```
var count = 1;
var newList;
var projectList = $('#projectList');

projectList.find('ul').remove().find('li').each(function(i) {
    if(i % 5 === 0) {
        newList = $('<ul>');
        newList.appendTo($('<div>').addClass('panel panel' + count++).appendTo(projectList));
    }

    newList.append(this);
});

projectList.cycle({
    fx: 'scrollVert',
    speed: 'fast',
    timeout: 0,
    prev: '.back',
    next: '.more'
});
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/vmdaM/99/)

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted... Your solution definitely makes the markup more correct, unwrapping the `ul` with inner `div`s into multiple `ul`s that only contain `li`s. I'm not sure I entirely like the `newList` building approach, but hey, it works :)

Comment: @rfunduk: Don't worry about it, it's a serial downvoter. And thanks :)